# Error installing Visual studio 11 on Windows 7

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-7, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

When I try to install Visual Studio 11 on Windows 7, and start it; I receive the following error. See the picture below:
[image]

Comment: I've found that unless you install from the full Windows 8 Developer Preview with Developer Tools 64-bit, there are plenty of problems.  Installing Win8 and then VS later doesn't seem to install all the libraries needed.  I went through 5 installs to figure that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message, you could try reinstalling [MS Sql Server](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/default.aspx), then run the Visual Studio installer again.